# QEMU: slow network performance with virtio_net driver

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm running KVM/QEMU 7.2.0 with Linux for both host and guest (kernel 6.1.6 on x86_64). For the virtual networking, I'm using bridge device on host to which guest attaches its NIC as `tap` device:

```
-netdev {"type":"tap","vhost":true,"id":"hostnet0"}
-device {"driver":"virtio-net-pci","netdev":"hostnet0","id":"net0"}
```

In terms of QEMU, the virtual guest network interface `virtio-net-pci` is supposed to have the best performance. However, `virtio-net-pci` gives me only ~0.3 MB/s receive speed in the guest, while for comparison switching the driver to `e1000e` gives me ~400 MB/s.

Through trial and error I have found out that if I set `napi_weight=1` parameter for `virtio_net` module in guest VM, the performance returns to normal.

After reading about NAPI I have come to understand that `napi_weight` parameter is used to switch between interrupt-based and polling-based servicing of received packets. Normally, the parameter defaults to `NAPI_POLL_WEIGHT` constant which is 64. I cannot understand the root cause of the problem and I don't want to be setting this parameter just because it *seems to do the trick*. It just feels wrong, i.e. I don't think I should be setting this parameter explicitly for `virtio_net` while `e1000` works out of the box. I'm also concerned about potential high CPU usage if I was to use this parameter.

Does anybody have any ideas what could be behind it and what I could try?

Comment: your question would be better if you included information about the specific NIC hardware.  There are lots of tweaks and gotchas specific to different hardware.

Comment: @BlindSpots What do you mean by "specific NIC hardware"? It's a virtual machine, so there is no hardware except for drivers.

Comment: It is using the hypervisor's hardware.

Comment: @PeterMaydell would you mind commenting on this?